# I can only see hello world in activities in android emulator, there is no icon in Apps

Tags: android, icons

I am trying to find Hello World icon in Apps but i cant see this icon whatever I do. There is no error, nothing wrong I follow tutorials from books, from net. I tried with 32bit and 64bit version of Eclipse too.

I can only see hello world in activities, that's all.

Edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="net.learn2develop.HelloWorld"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post your AndroidManifest. Let's see if everything is fine in there. :)

Comment: when u run a app on the emulator from eclipse there should be a app icon in th all apps section

Comment: Are you sure you set the name as hello world in the manifest? Are you sure you are using the correct android platform? Is your emulator set up correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is solution:

http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/troubleshooting.html

Help! My project won't build in Eclipse

If your project doesn't build, you may notice symptoms such as new resources added in the res/ sub-folders not showing up in the R class, the emulator not being started, not being able to run the application, or even seeming to run an old version of the application.

To troubleshoot these types of problems, first try:

Switch to the DDMS view in Eclipse (if you don't already have it open):
From the menu select Window > Open Perspective > Other
Select DDMS from the list and hit OK
In the Devices panel (top right panel by default), click on the down triangle to bring up the panel menu
Select Reset ADB from the menu, and then try running the application again